# jQuery: If JSON data matches ID InnerText, change CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geolocation, ip

I have a `div` with **customers IP** and **geolocation country**, then in another section I have a `div` with **customers country** (not based off IP but based off registration).

I have some `jQuery` running to search the customers login IP and grab the **country code + city**. What I **want to do** is once I have the `data.city` and `data.country_name` I want to have the script **check if the JSON country matches the account country**

```
$('#quick-links > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').on('click', function(){
  $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/'+$('#view-accounts > div.inner-content > div.login-history-grid.datagrid.expand.selected.focus > div.tbl > div.row.login-history.content-item.selected.focus > div.col.IP.Address').text()+'/json', function(data){
    alert(data.city);
    alert(data.country_name);
  });
});
```

**IPAddress selector=** `#view-accounts > div.inner-content > div.login-history-grid.datagrid.expand > div.tbl > div:nth-child(2) > div.col.IP.Address`

**Account Country selector=** `#customer-info > div.inner.info-view > div:nth-child(8) > label.country.hider.default > span`

I'm a bit lost on how to find if the `country_name` matches the `account country`
If they match, I want nothing to be done,
If they **don't match** I want to either alert or maybe change the `CSS` to highlight that **IP address**.

Comment: Are you sure that selector is specific enough ? Using an ID and then 15 classes could get you the wrong element ?

Comment: It's a work site and unfortunately they actually created the page this way and also have used the same ID's throughout the page also

Comment: What do your alerts say right now? If you do have data returning correctly, you would just match the result of the account country selector and result of data.country_name. Something that doesn't seem quite right is the `> div.col.IP.Address` part of your query selector, the div has both the 'IP' and 'Address' classes? Or is that supposed to be 'ipaddress' or the like?

Comment: The div for the ipaddress is actually `<div class="col IP Address"></div>` but the selector I posted is the selector I got from chrome's inspect element.

The alert is successfully returning the ipaddress each time for me, the difficulty is finding out how to match the json result with the account country